# DidSelectRowAt .. nothing happens

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to build an app with a tableView and so far I have made it to the point where I have a populated tableView, but I can't get anything to happen when I press the rows. Any help would be appreciated. If you are missing some code to help me just ask and I will post it.

With NSLog I have determined that the action is called when I press a row, but the next viewController isn't pushed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"DidSelectRow");

   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    galleriaDetailViewController *galleriaDetail = [[galleriaDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"galleriaDetail" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:galleriaDetail animated:YES];


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `self.navigationController` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Code looks fine (though naming convention on the vc starts with a cap).  Can you NSLog(@"%@", galleriaDetail); to see if you're getting a new vc?  The next suspect is that your navigationController is nil.  You can log that too.

Comment: Check out the spelling of "galleriaDetail.xib", maybe there is a misspell :)

Comment: Yeah @MaximMikheev!  I bet that nib name is "galleriaDetailViewController".  good catch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I'm still somewhat of a "noob" with xcode, so not sure were to check for your solutions. I have a storyboard so I'm not sure what the .xib-file would come from. Is this action incorrect if I just want to push to a viewController on the same storyboard? Before I have been able to ctrl-drag from a button to a view and use "modal" and it has worked, but not now. Sorry if I'm way off.

Comment: galleriaDetail is NSLogged as "<galleriaDetailViewController: 0xc97c279>" btw, sorry for not including that in my last comment.

Comment: You dragged which button to a view and set as modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments i have found out that you are using storyboard.If you are using storyboard means,then why you are trying to access a nib.

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"DidSelectRow");

   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    galleriaDetailViewController *galleriaDetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"galleriaView"]; // galleriaView is a identifier for that view.you have to set in your storyboard
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:galleriaDetail animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, as I said I've just recently started learning. After checking that the identifier is correct I tried it and still nothing happens. The row gets highlighted, and then nothing.

Comment: then exactly your problem is your navigation controller not working.you have to set a property for it in your AppDelegate and synthesize.I think it is autoreleased.you have to retain it.

Comment: The thing is when I have a button from my other view which uses "modal" (ctrl+drag to my galleriaDetailViewController) it works, but not when I do it from my tableView.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer now since it has led me the right way.  Thanks everybody for your help. It seems I was confusing nibs and storyboards and a few other things, so I just have to buckle down and wrap my head around it. Sorry for confusing others looking for a "real" answer, but the above is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your delegates? You need to set `myTableView.delegate = self;`and the set the datasource. You can hook up the delegate in interface builder or programmatically.

Comment: He's getting to the NSLog, so the delegates are probably okay.

Comment: Ahh sorry. I see now, yeah. I would have commented not answered but don't have the privileges yet :)

Comment: No worries.  Good of you to help out.  And not setting delegate/datasource is probably the #1 miss on these things, so it's a good thought.